# Pre-requisites for understanding an optimization algorithm

Tags: optimization, reference-request, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have never taken a course in convex optimisation. I would like to understand the algorithms used in this paper `dykstra'a algorithm and bregman projections: a convergence proof ' ( https://cmps-people.ok.ubc.ca/bauschke/Research/14.pdf ), at least at a heuristic level on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Can anyone suggest some pre-requisite reading since this is really not my area of math.

Comment: Please provide a DOI link.

Comment: Maybe read the nonspecialized chapters of "convex analysis" by Stephen Boyd.